# Passing EF object from controller to partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm very new to MVC and I want to pass an Entity object prepared in model from controller to partial view.

In model:

```
public class HomeSlidesViewModel
{
    public HomeSlidesViewModel()
    {

    }
    public List<HomeSlides> homeSlides { get; set; }
}
```

In controller:

```
    using wrrc.ViewModels;

    public ActionResult GetHomeSlider(HomeSlidesViewModel model)
    {
        var getHomeSliders =
            from ghs
            in Tools.DataModel.HomeSlides
            select ghs;
        model.homeSlides = getHomeSliders.ToList();
        return PartialView("_HomeSliderLayout", model);
    }
```

In view:

```
@model wrrc.ViewModels.HomeSlidesViewModel

@foreach (var slide in Model)
```

the problem is using Model in foreach and the error is :

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'wrrc.ViewModels.HomeSlidesViewModel' because
>   'wrrc.ViewModels.HomeSlidesViewModel' does not contain a public
>   definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Please help
Thanks

Comment: You need `@foreach(var slide in Model.homeSlides)`

Comment: @markpsmith Thanks :) that's my mistake

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
@foreach (var slide in Model)
```

You are telling the code to iterate over the `Model` list.  But `Model` isn't a list.  It's just a single object:

```
@model wrrc.ViewModels.HomeSlidesViewModel
```

That object *contains a property* which is a list.  Perhaps you meant to iterate over that?:

```
@foreach (var slide in Model.homeSlides)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you should try with below :

```
@foreach (var slide in Model.homeSlides){
  // Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: @MehdiAgharlou , Glad to help you ! If it solves your problem then you can accept this as an answer and close the question.